# In a mixed marriage is the Issur also on the Non-Jew?

Tags: gentiles, mitzvah, intermarriage, noahidism, leniencies

As far as I know I have not seen in the 7 laws of Bnei Noach that they have "Lifnei Iver"

Now of course a Jew cannot marry a Non-Jew. But is the Non-Jew in question also considered a Rasha?

The reason Im asking is I found out a person Im dealing with married a Jew and there are Halachic implications if someone is a Rasha.

Comment: Kozbi was killed along with Zimri, though that might have been a special case (ie she was doing it as part of a plot against the Bnei Yisrael, hence the war afterwards)

Comment: The gemara/rishonim at the beginning of avodah zara discusses if there is lifnei iver on a Jew to aid a non-jew commit a sin. Interesting point that there's no discussion the other way as you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember seeing in the writing of the Netziv that it is not a sin. This makes sense, because not marrying Jews is not one of the 7 Noahide commandments.

However, any non-Jew that is not committed to keeping the Noahide commandments (and very few are) is a sinner by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if it is a non Jewish woman:

> ...a Jewish male enters into relations with a gentile woman, when he
> does so intentionally, she should be executed. **She is executed because she caused a Jew to be involved in an unseemly transgression** (based on 1:16-18)
> ... This [punishment] is
> explicitly mentioned in the Torah, as (Vayikra 31:16-17) states:
> "Behold they were [involved] with the children of Israel according to
> the advice of Balaam. Execute any woman fit to know a man through
> lying with a male." - (Rambam Laws of Forbidden Relations 12:10)

Note the Maggid Mishna and Aruch Hashulchan argue on this Rambam and hold that the pasuk does not imply this.

Either way we have a source that a non-Jew causing a Jew to sin is punishable. Perhaps we can carry this back to the preceding halacha that a non-Jewish man who has relations with a Jewish woman is not executed, but has still committed this sin.

Comment: Note none of this can or should be applied to an actual situation, CLYOR

Comment: That does not mean she sinned. The Rambam is extending the Torah's ruling by an animal used for sin to a non-Jew. Obviously animals cannot sin.